# I know I'm good, but not that good

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

I'm editing and reediting my answer about `$(ls *.txt)` (I think it's bad) at [this Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944801/what-does-ls-txt-do/944806#944806) and have gotten 7 upvotes. However, on my User Summary page [waltinator](https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator?tab=topactivity) the question is shown with `+78` points.

[image: see].

Should I really get 78 points from 7 upvotes?

Comment: Looks like +8, -1, 80 minus 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Jacob Vlijm says](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17201/i-know-im-good-but-not-that-good#comment35515_17201), this is because the answer has recieved 8 upvotes and 1 downvote. Each upvote gives you +10 reputation and the downvote gives you -2.

This can be verified by [viewing the vote counts](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/established-user) on the post:

[image: screenshot showing separate counts of upvotes and downvotes]

Comment: (If you have 1k rep or a browser plugin)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Eliah linked, or if you just don't have the reputation to see the vote counts on a given post, [you can also just check your reputation tab under your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator?tab=reputation&sort=post), sort it by "post", and you'll see a listing of rep by post by day, and can expand things to see exactly when and how you were voted.

In your case, you'll see this (click the image to see the full-res):

[image]